# Where do the plastic boxes for screw containers come from?

Tags: satisfactory

Screws are one of the earliest things you gain the ability to produce in *Satisfactory*, and boy do you ever need to produce them!  They're likely to be one of your main bottlenecks for quite some times as you climb the tech tree, and you'll quickly become more familiar than you ever wanted to be with the sight of the big blue plastic containers holding a bunch of screws.

[image: Screw container]

Thing is... it's not until several tech tiers later that you unlock the ability to produce blue plastic, once you get oil and refineries.  So where were all those boxes for all those screws coming from in the interim?

[image: Plastic]

Comment: I have edited this post to remove the last line, clearing up any confusion, as per [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15830/250180)

Comment: Voting to reopen as per the meta posts: [When is it appropriate to close a lore question as “not addressed directly through in-universe sources”?](//meta.arqade.com/q/7673/4797) | [Is “This question requires developer only knowledge” the same thing as developer intent?](//meta.arqade.com/q/9901/4797) | [Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?](//meta.arqade.com/q/8473/4797)

Comment: How'd you arrive at the conclusion that the boxes are made from plastic? Why not iron?

Comment: @Shaun Because they look like plastic, not metal, and they're the exact same blue color as the Plastic material you're able to generate later on in the game.

Comment: Can we please see an in-game picture of the carton/box in question if it's easy enough to do?

Comment: I agree - looks plastic even when made only from Iron - https://satisfactory.fandom.com/wiki/Screw Also some later recipes does not make irl sense, but this one - literally unplayable (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 6):

Here are the few solutions I was able to come up with after a while of thinking:

1. **The boxes are made of some sort of metal.** Although an unlikely choice, there is a chance that the boxes are made of an unspecified type of metal (such as iron). However, it is the same color as the plastic boxes, which concludes it to be unlikely.
2. **The HUB came with some metal boxes that are unseen.** This is a bit of a plot-idea, but think about it; you need organization when you are trying to start factories on a new world! Perhaps the HUB came with some plastic boxes stowed away somewhere to help you clean up your mess.
3. **There is no answer.** Sometimes, random materials can come out of nowhere in video games. This is probably the most reasonable option and happens in many games, such as Minecraft. *(Where in the world did those iron crafting table tools come from?)*

But, these are the only logical solutions I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the first buildings you make have the screw boxes.

They can be found in the Equipment Workshop.
[image: Screw boxes in corner shelves of equipment workshop]

They can also be found in the Craft Bench.
[image: Screw boxes in middle of craft bench shelves.]